# Custom deserialiser for a nested HashMap with interface having two implementations using Jackson

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, jackson-databind

I have an object like

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomConfigDetailDeserializer.class)
    HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashMap<String, ConfigDetail>>> entityConfig;
```

Here `ConfigDetail` is an Interface.
I wish to have Custom Serialiser and Deserialiser for the above object.

The deserializer I have written does something like this:

```
public class CustomConfigDetailDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ConfigDetail> {

    @Override
    public ConfigDetail deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        for(Class clazz: ConfigDetailConstant.IMPLEMENTATIONS) {
            try {
                return (ConfigDetail)jsonParser.readValueAs(clazz);
            } catch (Exception e) { }
        }
        throw new InvalidDataException("Unrecognised Config Detail found for date " + jsonParser.getText());
    }
}
```

The `IMPLEMANTATIONS` set referenced above goes something like this:

```
public static class ConfigDetailConstant{
        static HashMap<String,HashMap<String, HashMap<String, DummyConfig>>> dummyConfig;
        static HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashMap<String, NotificationConfig>>> notificationConfig;
        public static final Set<Class> IMPLEMENTATIONS = Sets.newHashSet(dummyConfig.getClass(),notificationConfig.getClass());
    }
```

The class type of this is being returned as NULL.
I am confused on how to correctly do this.
Any Help is appreciated.

The JSON I wish to Convert to a POJO:

```
"entity_configuration": {
        "entity_config": {
            "INVOICE": {
                "default": {
                    "notification_config": {
                        "state": ["CREATED", "COMPLETED"],
                        "notification_type": ["email", "sms"]
                    },
                    "dummy_config": {
                        "name": ["ABC", "HELLO"]
                    }
                },
                "REGULAR": {
                    "notification_config": {
                        "state": ["COMPLETED"],
                        "notification_type": ["email"]
                    }
                }
            },
            "VARIANCE": {
                "default": {
                    "notification_config": {
                        "state": ["CREATED", "COMPLETED"],
                        "notification_type": ["sms"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You need to decide whether you implement a custom deserialiser for a type: `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashMap<String, ConfigDetail>>>` or for a `ConfigDetail` only. In case, you want to implement it only for a given interface you need to register deserialiser for an interface and do not need to create a class from `HashMap<String,HashMap<String, HashMap<String, DummyConfig>>>` or `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashMap<String, NotificationConfig>>>` type. Example payload and `POJO` model would be helpful.

Comment: I wish to create a deserialiser for complete tings. My POJO has this line only.  `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashMap<String, ConfigDetail>>>`

Comment: I don't wont to decouple the classes and add additional parameters to the JSON. @MichałZiober